# Assertion failure message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance

Assertion failure message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: OperationNotAllowed (caused by NullPointerException)

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that JMeter lacks [Java Heap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html) space. By default JMeter allocates for itself 512MB which is fine for tests development and debugging but not enough for the load test. I would suggest increasing this setting to ~70% of your total available physical RAM.

Look for the following line:

```
HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512
```

in

- `jmeter` file - if you're using Linux, Unix or MacOSX
- `jmeter.bat` file - if you're using Windows

and increase `-Xmx` setting accordingly.

You may also need to uncomment and tweak `NEW="-XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m"` line by the same factor and play with GC settings.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide for more detailed explanation of JVM settings and some more JMeter performance tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory of java process that you are using for JMeter.
It iss normal as JMeter by default has a very low heap allocation. It can be controlled using `-Xmx` parameter.

There is a line in  `jmeter.bat` for windows or `jmeter.sh` for non window platform script which recommends launching JMeter as

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" jmeter.sh
```

You can increase maximum heap size to the extent where you stop receiving these errors. I would suggest you to set it to more than 50% of your available RAM on the system that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I had some times problems with the logs, if you use the view results tree or view results in table options they store all the info in memory and that can create memory problems. To avoid that you can increase the memory as The_Amol said or/and save that info directly in a file with the Data Writer.